# Is a KD-Tree a unique ordering of a given data set?

Tags: data-structures, machine-learning, computational-geometry, kdtree

Given a set of data points, a [kdtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) is created over them, but is this kdtree a unique one?

Answer (score 4):

It appears to depend on how you construct the tree. The Wikipedia article mentions how the selection of the median point affects whether the generated tree is balanced or not. If a different point is selected, then the tree will not be balanced but will still be a kd-tree. Therefore, the answer to your question depends on exactly how your tree construction algorithm chooses the splitting planes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.

If the answer to your question were 'yes' then i think that would mean that the choice of **dimension** and **value** for each split were chosen by some objective criterion. The value of course is selected according to a precise algorithm (i.e., calculating the median of all points to be split in that dimension, but ***not*** the dimension. Most KD-Tree algorithms select the dimension to split just by alternating through the available dimensions. Some algorithms just randomly select the dimension to split on.

This is very different than a C4.5 (Decision Tree) because there, the dimension and value to split on are chosen by an objective criterion, i.e., entropy minimization (for categorical variables) or variance (for continuous variables).

Comment: well the value is unique but only once the dimension is specified (and i believe this includes root, as for all 'nodes'); again, though even for the root node, the choice of dimension in the implementations i'm aware of (and i checked several before responding to your Q) is just cycling through the available dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

It is unique or we call it stable when a certain splitting method is chosen, no matter what order those data lies in the data set.